# Inner join takes too much time, how can i speed it up?

Tags: sql

i have the next situation:

i had a table with a unique constraint of serie_id and user_id fields, i deleted it to try something and now i have duplicated rows (ie, two or more rows where the pair user_id AND serie_id are equals)

when trying to see the duplicated rows, i use this

```sql
SELECT t1.id 
FROM table_A t1 
INNER JOIN table_A t2 
ON t1.serie_id = t2.serie_id AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
WHERE t1.id < t2.id
```

but the table has A LOT of data so it takes too long. Is there a way to optimize it or speed it up?

edited: now im using this query to get all the ids of the duplicated rows,

```sql
SELECT id
FROM   table_A a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   table_A b
               WHERE  a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.serie_id = b.serie_id
               HAVING Count(*) > 1) 
Order by id desc
```

it also takes a lot of time, more than half an hour.

Also i want to keep, for each duplicated record, the original one, how can i exclude it from the results of this query?

I cannot use OVER or NUMBER_ROW as i saw in other comments, my version doesn't allow it

Sample Data:

```
id       serie_id         user_id
1          100              111
2          100              222
3          100              222
4          58               222
5          100              115
6          100              222
```

I want to delete the first two rows corresponding to the pair user_id:100 - serie_id=222
so the output would be:

```
id       serie_id         user_id
1          100              111
4          58               222
5          100              115
6          100              222
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Post the schema of the table including all column types and indexes. and grammar: if something takes too long, you don't want to "slow it down"; you want to _speed it up_.

Answer (score 0):

You must define Index for fields that you want to use in inner-join.
And also for fields that you want to use in WHERE clusers.

You can enable "Include Actual Execution plane" in SqlServer Managmenet Studio. SQL suggest you tips for increase performance of queries.

Answer (score 0):

To see the duplicate pair, you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.serie_id, t1.user_id, COUNT(*) CNT
FROM table_A t1 
GROUP BY t1.serie_id, t1.user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

And to return the actual rows, store the result in a temporary table and join it to the source table, like:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp
    CREATE TABLE #tmp ( serie_id INT, user_id INT, CNT INT)

INSERT INTO #tmp( serie_id, user_id, CNT )
    SELECT t1.serie_id, t1.user_id, COUNT(*) CNT
    FROM table_A t1 
    GROUP BY t1.serie_id, t1.user_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

SELECT t1.*, 
FROM table_A t1 INNER JOIN #tmp tmp on tmp.serie_id = t1.serie_id and tmp.user_id = t1.user_id
```

Anyway, an index on the `serie_id, user_id` columns should help.

Comment: I'm using this to return the id's of duplicated rows, but i wanna keep one of them while deleting the others
SELECT id
FROM   table_A a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   table_A b
               WHERE  a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.serie_id = b.serie_id
               HAVING Count(*) > 1) 
Order by id desc

Comment: I already have indexes on both serie_id and user_id